# monotouch: WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbum problems saving from camera

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, avcapturesession, alassetslibrary

Please see gist here: https://gist.github.com/1387224

Essentially, I'm trying to save a photo from the `AVCaptureSession`, I'm grabbing the output from an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, converting it into a UIImage and trying to send it to the `WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` method on `ALAssetLibrary`.

The reason for doing this is so I can grab the asset url once it's been saved (`UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum` works fine but doesn't let me extract the filename created)

The method is throwing an error

> Failed to encode image for saved photos.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I also looked at passing the raw `NSData` jpeg stream from the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` but can't work out how to get the metadata `NSDictionary` to pass through.

Many Thanks

Comment: would seem to be related to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` overloads that takes a `UIImage` were incorrectly bound (they should take a `CGImage` instead). This has now been fixed, and there is a hotfix available in this [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2166).

In the mean time you should be able to use the `WriteImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` that takes the raw `NSData` stream, passing a non-null `NSDictionary` (like in the [sample code](https://gist.github.com/1388126) in [this bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2166)).